# Bootstrap / Browser width calculation issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My row width is 1080 so ideally each col-md-1 would be

1080 / 12 = 90px

But col-md-8 width is showing up as 750px , Ideally it should be 720px

Same issue with col-md-4 , its showing up as 390px , instead of 360px.

There is no extra padding defined on the div as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is forcing the col-md-4 to show up on the next row instead of same row. What could i be doing wrong ?

### EDIT

Thanks for the reply but you are missing a serious note here, When you add up the width of col-md-8 and col-md-4, it would be equal to the row width. But that's not the case here.

750px (col-md-8) + 390px (col-md-4) != 1080px(row) 
its summing up to 1140, this is why, col-md is getting pushed to the next row.

Comment: This is how Bootstrap's grid system works. Grid columns have a constant [30px of gutter/padding by default](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6379674f35771ffe007f11bd498ad39c4defe8a4/less/variables.less#L321). (See also https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6379674f35771ffe007f11bd498ad39c4defe8a4/less/mixins/grid.less#L27 )

Comment: Sounds like what you're doing wrong is calculating the pixel widths of responsive columns. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

It's how the responsive grid system works.  Bootstrap adds a **row** margin of -15px (right and left) and a **column** padding right and left of 15px.

720px + 15px(left padding on column) + 15px(right padding on column) = 750px.  Once you put that in a row with -15px margin on each side you are back at your 720px.

You can "turn a fixed-width grid layout into a **full-width** grid layout by changing the container class to a fluid class": (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The more important question to look at here.  Do you want a responsive layout if you have specific pixel widths you are concerned about?